# Async Class not working to print out contents of JSON feed

Tags: java, android, json

My Async class will not display the contents of the JSON Feed and I am getting the error:

> 01-17 15:44:35.438: W/System.err(1732): org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray.

I am assuming my readJSONFeed method may be returning a null string but I cant figure out why. The code is below if anyone can see the problem I would be grateful.

```
public class JSONActivity extends Activity {

public String readJSONFeed(String URL) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
    try{
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if(statusCode == 200){
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null); {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }

        }else{
            Log.e("JSON", "Failed to download file");
        }
    }catch(ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return stringBuilder.toString();
}

private class ReadJSONFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls){
        return readJSONFeed(urls[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        try{
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            Log.i("JSON", "Number of surverys in feed: " +
                    jsonArray.length());


            //---print out the content of the JSON feed---
            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);


                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), jsonObject.getString("appeId") +
                        " - " + jsonObject.getString("inputTime"), 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_json);

new ReadJSONFeedTask().execute("http://extjs.org.cn/extjs/examples/grid/survey.html");

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.json, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

**log cat**

```
01-17 16:18:17.388: D/(1868): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7bd6ed0, tid 1868
01-17 16:18:17.458: W/EGL_emulation(1868): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-17 16:18:17.458: D/OpenGLRenderer(1868): Enabling debug mode 0
01-17 16:18:18.178: W/System.err(1868): org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray
01-17 16:18:18.228: D/dalvikvm(1868): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 240K, 10% free 3042K/3356K, paused 36ms, total 40ms
01-17 16:18:18.258: W/System.err(1868):     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
01-17 16:18:18.258: W/System.err(1868):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)
01-17 16:18:18.258: W/System.err(1868):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
01-17 16:18:18.258: W/System.err(1868):     at com.example.json.JSONActivity$ReadJSONFeedTask.onPostExecute(JSONActivity.java:66)
01-17 16:18:18.258: W/System.err(1868):     at com.example.json.JSONActivity$ReadJSONFeedTask.onPostExecute(JSONActivity.java:1)
01-17 16:18:18.258: W/System.err(1868):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
01-17 16:18:18.258: W/System.err(1868):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
01-17 16:18:18.258: W/System.err(1868):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
01-17 16:18:18.258: W/System.err(1868):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-17 16:18:18.268: W/System.err(1868):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-17 16:18:18.268: W/System.err(1868):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
01-17 16:18:18.268: W/System.err(1868):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-17 16:18:18.268: W/System.err(1868):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-17 16:18:18.268: W/System.err(1868):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
01-17 16:18:18.268: W/System.err(1868):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
01-17 16:18:18.268: W/System.err(1868):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post the complete logcat.

Comment: What does the data look like?

Answer (score 1):

You accidentally put a `;` after your while statement, so you don't actually have anything in your `StringBuilder` object, hence why your string is null when you get into `onPostExecute()`

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null); {  // <-- oops
    stringBuilder.append(line);
}
```

See if it works properly when removing the semicolon.

Comment: It worked after I removed the semicolon. It can't believe I didn't notice that before. Thanks for the advice @anddev84.

Answer (score 0):

Your error states the "object" you are trying to cast or catch as JSON is null so you need to handle that and yes your json is null so it'll crash right no attempt to read